# Is there a limit on the message size for SHA-256?

Tags: hash, sha256

When hashing a string, like a password, with SHA-256, is there a limit to the length of the string I am hashing? For example, is it only "safe" to hash strings that are smaller than 64 characters?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

There is technically a limit, but it's quite large. The padding scheme used for SHA-256 requires that the size of the input (in bits) be expressed as a 64-bit number. Therefore, the maximum size is (2<sup>64</sup>-1)/8 bytes ~= 2'091'752 terabytes.

That renders the limit *almost* entirely theoretical, not practical.

Most people don't have the storage for nearly that much data anyway, but even if they did, processing it all serially to produce a single hash would take an amount of time most would consider prohibitive.

A quick back-of-the-envelope kind of calculation indicates that even with the fastest enterprise SSDs currently<sup>1</sup> listed on Tom's hardware, and striping them 16 wide to improve bandwidth, just reading that quantity of data would still take about 220 years.

---

<sup>1. As of April 2016.</sup>

Comment: Block cipher techniques can be applied to inputs larger than and equal to 2^64 bytes.

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney: SHA-256 isn't a block cipher (or any other kind of cipher). It's a hash. Hashing can be applied to large inputs as well, of course--but larger than 2^64 bits (not to mention 2^64 bytes) isn't something most people need to worry about. Those who do will need to use something other than SHA-256 to do so (though depending on their needs, the only part they need to change may well be the padding).

Answer (score 7):

There is no such limit, other than the maximum message size of 2<sup>64</sup>-1 bits. SHA2 is frequently used to generate hashes for executables, which tend to be much larger than a few dozen bytes.

Comment: I try to understand your answer: Do you mean 2^{64}-1 bits or do you mean 65 bits length? 2^64 is quite a lot bits.

Comment: The former, @Stefan. Yep, that's a lot of bits. :-)

Comment: haha - ok yeah I don't need that much bits but that's good to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The upper limit is given in the NIST Standard [FIPS 180-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf#page=13). The reason for the upper limit is [the padding scheme](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87524/18298) to countermeasure against the MOV attack that Merkle-Damgard construction's artifact. The message length `l` is lastly appended to the message during padding.

> Then append the 64-bit block that is equal to the number `l` expressed using a binary representation

Therefore by the NIST standard, the maximum file size can be hashed with SHA-256 is `2^64-1` in bits ( approx 2.305 exabytes - that is close to [the lower range of the estimated NSA's data center in UTAH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utah_Data_Center), so you don't need to worry).

NIST enables the hash of the size zero message. Therefore the message length starts from `0` to `2^64-1`.

If you need to hash files larger than `2^64-1` then either use SHA-512 which has `2^128-1` limit or use SHA3 which has no limit.

Comment: Not that it matters much, an exabyte more or less ;), removed comments.

Answer (score 0):

So funny ya'll talk here about "**File Size**".
While the question was amount of "**Characters**".

for example:

- A password will not be 2.3 **exabytes**.
  The reason for setting maximum length, possibility of a denial of service attack.
- Someone could feed **exabytes** into an password field,
  pushing your server CPU or memory to it's limits,
  which would impact traffic a lot.

***So to answer this question, I would say:***

*"No there's no real limit for hashing, you could put millions of characters inside"*

*Although: "There's A maximum amount of characters we set for a password field"*

*So we can prevent these denial of service attacks.*