# Is there a limit on the message size for SHA3?

Tags: hash, cryptography, sha-3

With SHA2, there is a [limit on the message size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388177/is-there-a-limit-on-the-message-size-for-sha-256).

Is there a similar limit with SHA3?

Comment: This is no longer ontopic (2013 was over a decade ago) but is already answered by kelakala at the linked Q

Comment: Look at https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf

Comment: To be honest I don't see any direct mention of a limitation of the message size in the FIPS document where SHA-3 is defined. Now a limitation is of course not needed if none is present, but that won't directly answer the question. I'm happy to have this hosted on [crypto.se]. Otherwise the answer is (hidden) in the "Glossary / Terms and Acronyms" of the FIPS document.